# newbie question, why is my div not floating right?

Tags: html, css

Just wondering whats wrong with my code. It's wordpress, but I'm making a custom theme.
http://prime.programming-designs.com/blog/

Comment: Which div you want to be floated right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem

take out the `width:100%;` from the `#container`.

that is causing the side bar not to float right.

good luck

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please remove the `width:100%` for the `div` with id as `container` and then check

Answer (score 0):

theres maybe 2 errors but the most obvious is the margin of your #content div (300px?), you can also try to fix your #container width with a fixed value like 960px cause 100% is a bit buggy. and then your menu needs to be inside the #container...
or if you can't edit your code you can also set your #container width to less than 960px(~700px) and don't touch the code